# Fancybox 2.0 not working, very simple first test

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

My page is at www.danielcw.info.

At the bottom I am calling:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#single_1").fancybox({});
});
```

On:

```
<div id="single_1">
TESTTESTEST
</div>
```

Nothing happens.  Can anyone please explain where I am going wrong, I see all the JS and CSS loaded and on the page.

Thank you,
Daniel

Comment: since you have not used any custom settings you don't need to specify {} inside the .fancybox()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically, Fancybox is initialized on an anchor tag which points to a div element or a link housing the content to be shown on the Fancybox:

**HTML:**

```
<a href="#single_1" id="fancybox">Click here to launch Fancybox</a>

<div style="display:none">
    <div id="single_1">
        Content goes here
    </div>
</div>
```

**Javascript:**

```
$(function(){
    $('a#fancybox').fancybox({
        // Fancybox options here   
    })
    .trigger('click'); //Optional - if you wish to trigger the Fancybox after initialization
});
```

Comment: Good to note here that using my original code and adding the "trigger('click')" worked perfectly - +1 for the use of trigger here.

Answer (score 0):

Try using,

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("a #single_1").fancybox();
});

<a id="single_1" href="#">
TESTTESTEST
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You've merely instantiated the plugin. You have to trigger it now.

So you can add any DOM element and watch for an event then trigger the plugin.

```
<a href="#" class="fancyme">Click me</a>
```

The JS

```
$('fancyme').on("click", function() {
  $.fancybox('#single_1');
});
```

OR

You can trigger on page load

```
$(function(){
  $.fancybox('#single_1');
});
```